# Using HTML's conditional commenting: clarification on "gte"

Tags: html, conditional-comments

Is the HTML in this conditional comment seen by all non-IE browsers in addition to IE8, IE9, etc.?

`<!--[if gte IE 8]>html goes here<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It's a valid HTML comment so that code is hidden to non-IE browsers and IE 10 and 11 as they do not support conditional comments. So basically only IE 8 and IE 9 will see that content.

Comment: If ms rolled out automatic updates for ie like all the other browsers do they wouldn't need to either :/